# Separate distributions

Tags: distributions

Lets assume dataset with individuals that produce events that might or might not happen during each month of the year. Had it been completely random, we would see uniform distribution, however the histogram assumes some uneven behavior, for example seasonality.

So the question is - how to separate individuals that have uniform distribution of events from uneven distribution (any other distribution)?

I was thinking of applying some sum of square deviation from mean occurrences for each individual where less would imply uniform distribution. But the problem is - each individual might produce very different amounts of occurrences and therefore means are very different and non comparable. Which in turn makes it hard to separate uniform distribution with high amount of events from non-uniform with low amount of events.. What would be the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to identify those individuals with roughly uniform distributions, you could just create a rule and apply it (e.g., no more than a deviation of x% from expected in any month).  If you want to base your decisions on a statistical test for each individual, realize that the power of such tests to detected real deviations from uniform, if they exist, will be a function of sample size as well as size of deviation.  With large sample sizes, you might find no individuals with uniform responding.  In any case, you could test a null hypothesis of uniformity for one individual with a chi-sq test.  If you have a good idea what the non-uniformity will look like, you might be able to find a more powerful approach. Also, note that the chi square test assumes independence of events.  So, if your events are not independent, you will have to use a more nuanced approach.